# IPython Notebook keyboard shortcut search for text

Tags: replace, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a keyboard shortcut to search for text in an IPython Notebook?

I looked under Help | Keyboard shortcuts and there are lots of cool shortcuts but none for searching for text?

[image]

---

The notebook is running in FireFox on Ubuntu.

Comment: As for **Jupyter Lab**, just found out myself: Hit CTRL+F once and you're searching within a single cell. Hit CTRL+F twice and you're searching the whole notebook (though browser function).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There *is* a `find-and-replace` command in Jupyter. It's key binding is <kbd>F</kbd> (command mode):

[image]

Of course you can find text with the browser's functionality, (I find it sometimes better), but the command in Jupyter is also very useful. I use a lot that function `Replace in selected cells` when I copy-paste a bunch of code and then change variables or something like that:

[image]

---

(**Note:** You can launch the Command Palette with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and browse or run other commands)

---

Comment: had to use `ctrl` + `shift` + `F` to show command palette in my browser per https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/72#issuecomment-310640463

Comment: A couple of things changed in the meantime, I shall update the answer...

Answer (score 3):

As of Jupyter Lab v1.0.2 the CTRL+F twice press trick described in my comment above doesn't seem to work anymore.

I found the internal search functionality of jupyter lab pretty annoying, since it only searches in the current cell. I wanted to directly access the native browser search with CTRL+F.

To disable jupyter lab search function (and use browser search instead):

- open Settings\Advanced Settings Editor
- add the following to User Preferencec:

```js
{
    "shortcuts": [
    {
            "command": "documentsearch:start",
            "keys": [
                "Accel F"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-mod-searchable",
            "disabled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

This will override the System Default, with `"disabled": true` added, and enables Browser CTRL+F in all Jupyter Lab instances.

Answer (score 3):

Enter Command Mode by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>, followed by *find and replace* key binding <kbd>f</kbd>, so

<kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd>

[Take the *User Interface Tour* (Help Menu) if you haven't already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wNJW.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the cell(s) in which you want to replace.
2. Then just click outside those cells
3. Press f.

You are done!

Answer (score 1):

:Embarassed: "Running in" means use the browser "find text on this page" shortcut.
Firefox shortcut for this is ctrl - F.