# Renaming a variable everywhere in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to rename a variable everywhere in your current jupyter notebook file?

I.e. let's say my notebook referencing a variable "foo" in multiple functions and locations through my script. Later I decide I want to rename this variable to "bar" for better readability...

In xcode, you can highlight and right click to do this. Sort of a smart search/replace command.

Would love to be able to do the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126049/7019148

Comment: Imho this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119831/ipython-notebook-keyboard-shortcut-search-for-text. There is a huge semantic difference between renaming a variable and a simple text replace: without direct user interaction, the second replaces all instances of a certain text while the first can be way more clever, e.g. checking if an occurrence of the text actually is a variable name. Cf. the rename-variable functionalities in other IDEs. To the question itself: seems this unfortunately is not provided in Jupyter atm.

Comment: Using the inbuilt find-and-replace method, I've found matching words with regex helpful for refactoring variables: `\bfoo\b`, then replace with `bar`. It's still pretty dumb in that it cant' distinguish variables vs. strings, but better than nothing.

Comment: True variable renaming can be down with jupyterlab and the [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp) extension.

Answer (score 11):

It is a bit late, but it could help someone.

1- Go to "Edit", then "Find and Replace".

2- Enter the two words in Find and Replace respectively.

3- Click on the small arrow in order to rename all the occurences in your jupyter notebook.[image]

Answer (score 7):

I hope you have already solved this. But, my answer will help someone who has similar problem like that.
I think this can be accomplished using the Find and Replace option which can be found under the edit menu of the notebook. If you're in command mode, you can easily press the F key and bring up the find and replace dialog. Thank you!

Comment: But this "Find and Replace" doesn't understand the context. E.g. variables in different functions may have the same names, and you may want to change the names in only one function.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a bit late, but I found a simple solution:

```
1 - shift+click in first cell

2 - shift+click in last cell

3 - Press F or go to Edit/Find and Replace

4 - Rename the expression you need.
```

Comment: Sorry, I have just discovered that there is a "Replace in all cells" button inside the Find and Replace menu, just next to the text input box.

Answer (score 3):

From a Mac, highlighting and using control-right click gives an option (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> is a shortcut) to change all occurrences. I suspect this is what you want, but if your variable names are too short (e.g. i, j, k), it could really mess up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Ctrl + F

Then replace the variable