# Changing same word in code at the same time with google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, shortcut

I'm using colab to work on python projects and was wondering if there was a way to highlight a certain text and change that text for all of the other places in the code.
Example:

```
variable = 1
variable2 = variable + 1
```

And then change `variable` to `var` without having to individually change every single line

```
var = 1
var2 = var + 1
```

Comment: The feature you're asking about is usually called "refactoring" in other development environments, FYI. Another common term for it is "renaming". Here's a post that looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177616/renaming-a-variable-everywhere-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: You could change the editor key bindings to `vim` and then run a command to change all the occurrences of `variable` to `var`. But this only works for a single cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Find and Replace on the Edit tab. Another useful trick is clicking in every place you want to edit while pressing alt and you have multiple text cursors editing at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Google colab uses the same keys short-cuts of microsoft VS, just use `Ctrl+D` to add to the selection the next occurrence.

Use instead `Ctrl+Shift+L` to select all occurrence.

Once you selected the occurrences you can edit them by just typing the new name.

If you use short variable names ( as `X`) this method will probably not work, as every word with an `x` in it will also change.