# Google colab change variable name everywhere in code cell

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I highlight a variable within a cell in colab, all the instances of that variable shines up.

[image]

Is it possible to change all these instances of the variables at the same time and if such, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing same word in code at the same time with google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070361/changing-same-word-in-code-at-the-same-time-with-google-colab)

Comment: google colab uses the same keys short-cuts of microsoft VS, just use Ctrl+d to add to the selection the next occurrence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google colab uses the same keys short-cuts of microsoft VS, just use `Ctrl+D` to add to the selection the next occurrence.

Use instead `Ctrl+Shift+L` to select all occurrence.

Once you selected the occurrences you can edit them by just typing the new name.

If you use short variable names ( as `X`) this method will probably not work, as every word with an `x` in it will also change.

Comment: Thank you so much You saved me a lot of time